# Forward Start Spread Options

Tags: option-pricing, finance-mathematics, mathematics, asset-pricing

> **Question:**
>   We have a spread option with payoff: $\max (P_{T} - HR\times G_T, 0)$, where $P$, $G$ are underlying prices and $HR$ is a constant.
>
> At time zero only contract $G$ is available for trading. The contract $P$ will only open trading at $0 < t_1 < T$.
>
> What's the (optimal i.e. risk neutral expectation based) price of the contract assuming joint lognormality.

I am a bit confused on where to start with this question. Unless I am incorrect are there different cases to consider before we price the contract? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At $t_1$, this payoff can be priced using the Margrabe formula as used for pricing an exchange option.

See Margrabe Formula [here](http://web.math.ku.dk/~rolf/EQF_Margrabe.pdf)

Using the notations in the question and those used the hyperlinked document above -

$Price_{t_1} = P_{t_1}e^{(\mu_P-r)\tau}\Phi(d_+) -HR \times   G_{t_1}e^{(\mu_G-r)\tau}\Phi(d_-) \tag{1}$

$Price_0$ is the discounted value of $Price_{t_1}$ using the discount factor $e^{-rt_1}$

$P_{t_1}$ is assumed to be known at time $0$ - e.g. $P$ begins trading at $t_1$ at par, such that we know that $P_{t_1} = 100$. Otherwise $P_{t_1}$ needs to be estimated by other means.

So, the only unknown we are left with in $(1)$ is $G_{t_1}$.

$G_{t_1}$ is random at $t_1$ but it's distribution is known.

Hence, the brute force method would be to find the expectation of $Price_{t_1}$ by numerical integration of  $(1)$ over the known probability distribution of $G_{t_1}$ (lognormal distribution).

$Price_0 = e^{-rt_1}\mathbf{E}(Price_{t_1})$

$Price_0 = e^{-rt_1}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}Price_{t_1}pdf(G_{t_1}(x))dx$

Comment: Gordon in the house woot woot!! Guessing that means this solution is sound :)

Comment: What does the pde() function stand for? Probability density estimation?

Comment: Yes, i meant it to be probability density function. "pdf" would have been a better acronym to use.

Comment: Any chance you know this one: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/45640/finding-the-extrinsic-value-of-an-option-with-conditions?